# Do I have to add "one" to refer to a last used noun?

Tags: grammaticality, pronouns

While reading George R. R. Martin's *A Song of Ice and Fire: A Game of Thrones* I stumbled upon this sentence:

> His voice cracked like a boy's.

I think to remember from my English lessons in school that *one* should be added at the end to refer to the last used known noun, like so:

> His voice cracked like a boy's *one*.

Which is deemed grammatically correct?

Comment: I'd use the first sentence. Adding "one" sounds awkward; but both are grammatically correct.

Comment: @DavidWallace: Really? The second one sounds definitely wrong to me.

Comment: His voice cracked like your voice, or like yours.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to Swan (*Practical English Usage*):

> One(s) is not normally used after a noun with possessive 's. Instead, we can either just drop one(s) or use a structure with 'that/those of' (more formal).

The formal version of the OP's example would be: *His voice cracked like that of a boy.*

The OP is possibly thinking of the "rule" whereby *one* is often used instead of repeating the last noun. Swan's examples:

- Which is your boy? The **one** in the blue coat.
- I'd like a cake. A big **one** with lots of cream.

Comment: Not just possibly, I was definitely thinking of that rule.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the 'one' as it is implied from the sentence. Both appear grammatically correct, but it seems more common to leave it out.

It is certainly less awkward to leave it off.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the rule that you were thinking of, I will add some further points.

You use *one/ones* to avoid repeating a countable noun. E.g. in the sentence

> She was wearing her new dress, the red one.

*one* replaces dress and **cannot be omitted**. Adjectives cannot stand alone as e.g. in German.

You can place one/ones behind *the*, *this*, *that* and *which*. After *the* it is necessary, after *this/that* it is usual, and after *which* it's possible to omit.

> This dog is very cute, but I'd like to adopt that one. Or which (one) would you rather take?

Comment: Strangely, in your first example, "one" *can* be omitted. In that particular sentence it would be a bit awkward, but in similar sentences it would not even be awkward. "She was opening her first bottle of wine, the red." In your second example, "I like to adopt that one" is awkward. It would be better as "I *would* like".

Comment: @MετάEd Well, you say in this sentence it sounds slightly awkward. And your example in which you think it is perfectly fine, I'm not very surprised that you choose "wine" which is usually white or red, though blue, green, ... exists. I'm interested in what do you think in general about sentences in which the color (or rather adjective) is not a crucial part of the, um, thing (proper noun? Not sure). I guess you know what I mean. Let's take the dog example. "She's going to adopt that dog over there, the black-spotted (one)." Isn't *one* necessary and isn't it awkward again without *one*?

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert to talk about the underlying grammatical part of the sentence in question, but leaving out *one* seems more succinct and natural.